# Should one perform geometry optimisation before calculating electronic/phonon band structures via DFT?

Tags: density-functional-theory, band-structure, electronic-structure, phonons, phonon-dispersion

I am new to DFT calculations and I would like to get the electronic and phonon band structures of FeSn (1 kagome layer and 1 Sn layer in between). My question is, is it absolutely necessary to first do a geometry optimisation before performing the electronic and phonon band structures? I will be using the density functional perturbation theory (DFPT) method to calculate the phonon dispersion. The code I shall be using is Elk.

Comment: Yes, at least for phonon calculations, it is **absolutely necessary** to first do a geometry optimisation. Lattice dynamics assumes atoms at mechanical equilibrium. Coordinates must be well converged with *forces* close to zero, otherwise calculation will return imaginary frequencies. Hence *not only* is geometry optimization necessary, but **high convergence tolerances** are required as a first step towards a good lattice dynamics calculation.

Answer (score 9):

1. For the **electronic band structure**, I'd say it's debatable.

For consistency reasons, it would make sense for example to perform a geometry optimization with PBE and calculate its PBE band structure. So we'd be reporting the PBE band structure of a PBE optimized structure.

On the flip side, it is common for people to do PBE geometry optimization and use a hybrid (HSE06 for example) for the band structure calculation, because doing a geometry optimization with a hybrid is very expensive. So, in this case we'd report a HSE06 band structure of a PBE optimized structure.

Of course, the next relevant question is whether we can use an experimentally obtained structure that might not be the most stable configuration in our DFT calculations. I *have* seen examples of this for experimental papers where DFT was used to give insight or corroborate the experimental results, but for purely computational studies I find that people usually relax the structures according to the level of DFT theory (LDA, GGA, hybrid, etc) and choice of parameters (k-point mesh, plane-wave cutoffs, etc). This is just my impression, so take it with a pinch of salt.

2. For the **phonon band structure**, I'd say it's necessary.

I think it is a technical requirement to perform the geometry optimization first if you're working in the harmonic approximation where you assume that you are at the bottom of a quadratically shaped basin (with respect to the ionic displacements) in the energy landscape. This is explained clearly by ProfM [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/how-to-deduce-phase-transitions-from-a-phonon-calculation?rq=1) and [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9325/stability-using-phonon-calculation). This [discussion](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/2107/6131) on how low the forces should be to converge phonon energies also seems useful for you to look at. I suspect that one might face convergence issues and *maybe* artificial soft modes if the geometry optimization is not performed beforehand.